# NHibernate and 2 connectionstrings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Currently trying to use 2 different connectionstrings in a function. We have 2 databases with users. They work for the same company but in 2 different buildings. For this, they've set up 2 databases. Users from building A are also in the users table of building B and vice versa. The difference is that the user is not "active" on the building where they do not work.

What I am trying to do right now is simple: I check wether the user exists and is active in the default database, set a variable for the result and then I do a simple if else statement and execute the timeregistration procs.

For this I've written this function:

```
public static RegistrationData LogOnOffCheckBothDBs(int IdType, string userId, string isahUserCode)
        {
            //To do: Check wether the user is active or not in the default database. 
            var setting = 0;
            RegistrationData Obj = null;
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                //userCheckDb == 0 => Database1. als 1 => Database2.
                var userCheckDb = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec SIP_KWI_ObsInd_sel :Id, :IdType") //Proc that returns if user is active or not
                .SetString("Id", userId)
                .SetInt32("IdType", IdType)
                .UniqueResult<int>();
                setting = userCheckDb;
                session.Dispose();
            }
            if(setting == 1) //If user is not active on default database -> Execute proc in the second connn string (OpenSessionDB2) 
            {
                using (ISession session1 = NHibernateHelper.OpenSessionDb2())
                {
                    var result = session1.CreateSQLQuery("exec SIP_KWI_LogOnOff_prc :Id, :IdType, :IsahUserCode ")
                       .AddEntity(typeof(RegistrationData))
                       .SetString("Id", userId)
                       .SetInt32("IdType", IdType)
                       .SetString("IsahUserCode", isahUserCode)
                       .UniqueResult<RegistrationData>();

                    Obj = result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
                {
                    var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec SIP_KWI_LogOnOff_prc :Id, :IdType, :IsahUserCode ")
                       .AddEntity(typeof(RegistrationData))
                       .SetString("Id", userId)
                       .SetInt32("IdType", IdType)
                       .SetString("IsahUserCode", isahUserCode)
                       .UniqueResult<RegistrationData>();

                    Obj = result;
                }
            }

            return Obj;
        }
```

The if condition is all good, when I put breakpoints everything runs at it should. So the proc SIP_KWI_ObsInd_sel works correctly and returns the correct value.

However, for some reason.

```
 if(setting == 1) //If user is not active on default database -> Execute proc in the second connn string (OpenSessionDB2) 
            {
                using (ISession session1 = NHibernateHelper.OpenSessionDb2())
                {
                    var result = session1.CreateSQLQuery("exec SIP_KWI_LogOnOff_prc :Id, :IdType, :IsahUserCode ")
                       .AddEntity(typeof(RegistrationData))
                       .SetString("Id", userId)
                       .SetInt32("IdType", IdType)
                       .SetString("IsahUserCode", isahUserCode)
                       .UniqueResult<RegistrationData>();

                    Obj = result;
                }
            }
```

This still executes on the wrong database(the default one) and not on my second database.

Additional info(Nhibernate classes)

```
private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012                  
                  .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Isah")).ShowSql()
                  )
                  .ExposeConfiguration(
                        x =>
                        {
                            // Increase the timeout for long running queries
                            x.SetProperty("command_timeout", "180");

                            // Allows you to have non-virtual and non-public methods in your entities
                            x.SetProperty("use_proxy_validator", "false");
                        })
                  .Mappings(m =>
                            m.FluentMappings
                                .AddFromAssemblyOf<Tool>())

                  .BuildSessionFactory();


                }

                return _sessionFactory;
            }

        }
        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactoryDB2
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012                  
                  .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Isah2")).ShowSql()
                  )
                  .ExposeConfiguration(
                        x =>
                        {
                            // Increase the timeout for long running queries
                            x.SetProperty("command_timeout", "180");

                            // Allows you to have non-virtual and non-public methods in your entities
                            x.SetProperty("use_proxy_validator", "false");
                        })
                  .Mappings(m =>
                            m.FluentMappings
                                .AddFromAssemblyOf<Tool>())

                  .BuildSessionFactory();


                }

                return _sessionFactory;
            }

        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public static ISession OpenSessionDb2()
        {
            return SessionFactoryDB2.OpenSession();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `_sessionFactory` private field for both session factories.  Create one for each, e.g. `_sessionFactory` and `_sessionFactoryDB2`

So when you create SessionFactoryDB2 your check for `_sessionFactory == null` will be true as it was set for SessionFactory.  You need another backing field for SessionFactoryDB2

```
private static ISessionFactory SessionFactoryDB2
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactoryDB2 == null)
                {
                    _sessionFactoryDB2 = Fluently.Configure()
```